# Given a chi-squared distribution, find $\Pr(\mu-2\sigma \leq Y \leq \mu + 2\sigma)$

Tags: r, self-study, chi-squared-distribution

Given a chi-squared distribution of df = 8, which R command do I use in order to find $\Pr(\mu-2\sigma \leq Y \leq \mu + 2\sigma)$? That is, the probability that $Y$ lies within 2 standard deviations of its mean?

I know that $\mu=8$ and $\sigma=4$.

Comment: Why do you think you should use the chi-squared distribution here? Do you mean to ask about $Y^2$?

Comment: I think I'm justing looking for the probability that the variable $Y$ lies between 0 and 16. I've found the command I needed: pchisq(16, df=8). Thank you.

Comment: That will output the probability of a random variable distributed as chi-squared w/ 8 df being <= 16. If that's what you're after, why not make it an official answer & accept it?

Comment: `df=8;pchisq(df+2*sqrt(2*df),df)-pchisq(df-2*sqrt(2*df),df)`

Comment: It's quite interesting to make df a vector (say 1:99) and plot the result of the above calculation - for df≥0.25, the probability is never more than about 0.0055 off the corresponding value for the normal. (The local maxima and minima in that range occur at about 0.25, 1.24 and 12.75 df)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the function `pchisq` to calculate the probability on the interval you specified which is really the interval $[0,16]$. So you can do the following:

```
> pchisq(16,df=8)
[1] 0.9576199
```

The `pchisq` function as written computes the probability for all values below 16, but since the support of the chi-square distribution is for numbers greater or equal to zero, the probability of before the value 0 is just zero. So what I have written should be the answer.